# System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] issue in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with mvc4 and C#

i have a model

```
 public class Prod {
    private List<string> _photos;      
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       

    public IEnumerable<string> Photos {
        get {
            if (_photos == null) {
                getPhotos();
            }
            return _photos;
        }
        private set{
            _photos = value.ToList();
        }
    }
```

and take this in a list at controller

```
  List<Prod> products = new Products().ToList();            
  return View(products);
```

in Photos contain a string i try to show that string in View page,

```
@model List<...Products.Prod>
 @foreach (var pro in Model)
 {
     @pro.Photos;
 }
```

i got the value as  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]. How can i get corresponding string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property `Photos` is a collection so

```
@foreach (var pro in Model)
{
  @pro.Name;
  foreach (string item in pro.Photos)
  {
    @item;
  }
}
```